# XOR Combinations

Tags: logic, binary, bit-strings

Given a binary number X of length M, which is XOR of N numbers, find out number of unique combinations of N binary numbers of length M such that their XOR is equal to X

. Two combinations are said to be different if there is at least one number which is in Combination 1 and not in Combination 2.

Input Format:
The first line of standard input contains T
, the number of test cases.
For each test case, there will be 2 lines.
First line of each test cases consists of 2 integers: N and M.
Second line consists of number X

in binary number system.

Output Format:
For each test case, print to standard output the number of unique combinations of N
binary numbers whose XOR is equal to X.

EXAMPLE:

1

2 2

10

ans=4

Explanation

We need to find combination of all 2 numbers whose XOR
will give the value 10.

The possible numbers are:

1. 10 and 00
2. 11 and 01
3. 00 and 10
4. 01 and 11

How can i solve this problem using dynamic programming?

```
Input Constraints:
1≤T≤10
1≤N≤10^5
1≤M≤10^5
```

Output Constraints:

```
Print the answer after applying modulo (%) operation with 10^9+7
```

Comment: In your example, it looks like 1 and 3 (as well as 2 and 4) are the same solution ...  So shouldnt the answer be 2?   Also, would you want to restrict $N \le 2^M$ ... or can $N > 2^M$, in which there have to be numbers that are the same?

Comment: yes so basically order is also considered

Comment: The problem is more interesting if you want to count sets of _distinct_ $M$-bit numbers that xor up to $X$. Unfortunately the example in the problem does not really clarify if repetitions are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: writing **XOR** as $\oplus\,$, the operator is commutative, associative and nilpotent $A \oplus A = 0\,$, which implies that $A \oplus B=C \iff A=B \oplus C\,$.

For any $N-1$ arbitrary numbers $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_{N-1}\,$ of length $M\,$, there exists one unique $X_N$ such that $X_1\oplus X_2 \oplus\cdots\oplus X_{N-1}\oplus X_N=X\,$, given by $X_N=X\oplus X_1 \oplus X_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus X_{N-1}\,$.

Comment: is the answer always summation of (2^N)

Comment: There are $2^M$ distinct $M$-bit numbers, and however you choose $N-1$ of them, the $N^{th}$ one can be determined from the **XOR** condition, as shown above. I hope that you can finish it off from there, though the question doesn't make it clear what you count as *different* combinations.

Comment: actually i've pasted the whole problem as it is ...didn't even put a single comma by myself